# Присвоение имени переменной значением другой

Tags: c#, .net

По определённым причинам мне нужно сделать так, чтобы значение переменной string  1 переменной могло присваиваться второй переменной как имя.
Пример кода:

```
string name = "example";
int {name} = n;
```

Будет ли такой код работать? На данный момент не представляется возможным протестировать.
Прошу учесть, что я не переименовываю int на другое имя, а именно создаю новую с именем значения другой переменной.

Comment: т.е. вы хотите чтобы этот код был эквивалентен `int example = n;`, верно?

Comment: миллениалы изобретают классы))))) простите, пожалуйста, не удержался)

Comment: Именно, но мне нужно, чтобы пользователь сам вводил имя переменной, я решил реализовать это так.

Comment: Ну, я только начал изучать шарп, конечно, зря пытаюсь залезть наперёд, но стараюсь уже начать писать мини-проектики чтобы закрепить то, что узнал)

Comment: Си шарп - язык с достаточно сильной типизацией, а вы хотите её поломать, сделав создание переменных в рантайме. То, что вы хотите реализовать либо невозможно свойствами этого языка, либо сильно затруднено -- вы сами запутаетесь такой код читать. Вам стоит пересмотреть необходимость решения задачи таким способом. Ради такого сценария так никто не делает, вы просто зря тратите своё время. Как частичный вариант решения - посмотрите в сторону словаря.

Comment: @IPBlade мне кажется, раз вы только начали свой путь, вам стоит написать здесь "зачем вы хотите так сделать". скорее всего ваша идея реализуется другими способами (я подозреваю что через Классы).

Comment: Понял, благодарю. Просто дело в том, что я хочу сделать простенький каталог баз данных на основе массивов, в одной из команд нужно как раз- таки создать массив, а имя должно было браться из введённого string, который использовал пользователь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это невозможно. Переменная - это то, что определяется на этапе компиляции, то есть в момент выполнения самой переменной не существует, существует только код ассемблер для выполнения на процессоре, где внутри понятия переменных вообще нет. Там есть только регистры и память, никак не относящиеся к тому, что вы пишете в коде.

Но в C# есть структрура данных, подходящая под вашу задачу - словарь `Dictionary`.

```cs
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict["example"] = 1;
Console.WriteLine(dict["example"]);
```

Или даже так, протестируйте, выполните пошагово, разберитесь, как работает

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите имя значения (Enter для выхода): ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        if (name.Length == 0)
            break;
        Console.Write("Введите значение: ");
        dict[name] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Введено значений: {dict.Count}");

    foreach (var pair in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} = {pair.Value}");
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Введите имя значения (Enter для выхода): вася
Введите значение: 22
Введите имя значения (Enter для выхода): привет
Введите значение: 800
Введите имя значения (Enter для выхода): !!===
Введите значение: 1
Введите имя значения (Enter для выхода): 1234 моя переменная
Введите значение: -333
Введите имя значения (Enter для выхода):
Введено значений: 4
вася = 22
привет = 800
!!=== = 1
1234 моя переменная = -333
```

Стоит заметить, что в отдельно взятом словаре все ключи и все значения меют один и тот же тип. Для примера выше ключ словаря - это `string`, а значение - `int`.

Comment: Да, плюс к словарю. Единственное, стоит честно предупредить, что это случай простой - все переменные в словаре имеют тип целых чисел, а такого чтобы пользователь ввёл одну строку, одно целое и одно вещественное - это будет уже надо городить огород или делать три словаря.

Comment: Так, всё-таки я не слишком понял: нельзя изменять значения переменных во время выполнения программы впринципе или всё же есть исключения? Я делал калькулятор на переменных типа  double и задавал их через вводимые в консоль значения.

Comment: @IPBlade значения меняйте сколько влезет. Имена нельзя менять. Объявление со значением: `int i = 3`, изменение значения `i = 5`. `string name = "Вася"`, `name = "Петя"`. Тип переменной нельзя поменять, так же как и имя.

Comment: Чисто технически, это касается только локальных переменных :)

Comment: Я хочу не поменять имя переменной, а назначить новую с именем значения другой переменной.

Comment: Я уже понял, что в таком случае лучше реализовывать всё через словарь, но мне так же нужно, чтобы в массивах были кое-какие значения. Я также рассматриваю использование файлов для хранения данных вместо массивов, но при этом файлов может быть бесконечно много, а в случае с массивом понадобится только один в качестве набора сохранённых массивов.

Comment: @IPBlade Изучайте структуры данных, у меня нет красной таблетки от всех вопросов.